# Which linux command is used to find numbers or words between two different characters (first will be a word and last will be symbol)?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, unix

```
“With clarity and definition is associated *"id"='o123-3923-d2i71-0129p' ,a certain physical spareness. Most of the "id"='s0987-3923-d2i71-0129p' great deciduous trees of England give one the impression, at any rate in summer, of being rather o "id"='p4523-3923-d2i71-0129p' ,bese. In Scandinavian mythology Embla, the elm, was the first woman. Those who have lived "id"='o123-3923-d2i71-0129p' ,much with old elm trees—and I spent a good part of my boyhood under their ponderous shade—will "id"='m0962-3923-d2i71-0129p' ,agree that the Scandinavians were men of insight. There is in effect something blowsily female about those vast trees that brood with all their bulging masses of foliage above the meadows of "id"='o123-3923-d2i71-0129p' ,the home counties.
```

Here I want to get only id. Output:

```
"id"='o123-3923-d2i71-0129p' "id"='s0987-3923-d2i71-0129p' "id"='p4523-3923-d2i71-0129p' "id"='o123-3923-d2i71-0129p'"id"='m0962-3923-d2i71-0129p'"id"='o123-3923-d2i71-0129p'
```

Comment: nope:( that paragraph is not related to my requirement those are confidential thats why i changed entire. i just want to know the linux command for that particular statement.

Comment: I _think_ you’re looking for `grep`, but since you tagged this _Linux_ I don’t know whether you want a command line utility or a system call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```sh
#! /bin/bash

exec <<EOF
“With clarity and definition is associated *"id"='o123-3923-d2i71-0129p' ,a certain physical spareness. Most of the "id"='s0987-3923-d2i71-0129p' great deciduous trees of England give one the impression, at any rate in summer, of being rather o "id"='p4523-3923-d2i71-0129p' ,bese. In Scandinavian mythology Embla, the elm, was the first woman. Those who have lived "id"='o123-3923-d2i71-0129p' ,much with old elm trees—and I spent a good part of my boyhood under their ponderous shade—will "id"='m0962-3923-d2i71-0129p' ,agree that the Scandinavians were men of insight. There is in effect something blowsily female about those vast trees that brood with all their bulging masses of foliage above the meadows of "id"='o123-3923-d2i71-0129p' ,the home counties.
EOF

grep -oP '"id"='\''\w{4,5}-\w{4}-\w{5}-\w{5}'\'
```

Btw: [Lorem ipsum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorem_ipsum) is a good way to generate random text data, which gets easily understood by everyone. There are many online generators available.